# Is it possible to start using Django's migration system after years of not using it?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-migrations

A project I recently joined, for various reasons, decided not to use Django migration system and uses our own system (which is similar enough to Django's that we could possibly automate translations)

## Primary Question

Is it possible to start using Django's migration system now?

### More Granular Question(s)

Ideally, we'd like to find some way of saying "all our tables and models are in-sync (**i.e. there is no need to create and apply any migrations**), Django does not need to produce any migrations for any existing model, *only* for changes we make.

---

- Is it possible to do this?

  - Is it simply a case of "create the django migration table, generate migrations (necessary?), and manually update the migration table to say that they've all been ran"?
- Where can I find more information for how to go about doing this? Are there any examples of people doing this in the past?

---

#### Regarding SO Question Rules

I didn't stop to think for very long about whether or not this is an "acceptable" question to ask on SO. I *assume* that it isn't due to the nature of the question not having a clear, objective set of criteria for a correct answer. *however*, I think that this problem is surely common *enough*, that it could provide an extremely valuable resource for anyone in my shoes in the future. Please consider this before voting to remove.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably be able to do `manage.py makemigrations` (you might need to use each app name the first time) which will create the migrations files.  You should then be able to do `manage.py migrate --fake` which will mimic the migration run without actually impacting your tables.

From then on (for future changes), you would run makemigrations and migrate as normal.